# \n not being highlighted in vscode python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The backslash n is not being highlighted as usual in vscode with the pink color.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4oXc.png)

Comment: you probably need to install the python extension....

Comment: What extensions have you installed? The `print` is not even highlighted.